# Are there any open plant databases (database/library/collection), containing species information and pictures?

Tags: bioinformatics, botany, species-identification, taxonomy, database

I would like to download a plant database containing photos and species details. Do you know if there are any openly available online?

Comment: What about [EOL](http://eol.org/)?

Answer (score 5):

Large online [floras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flora_%28publication%29) have the advantage of not only having details and often photographs and illustrations, but also being (more or less) definitive, that is, botanists will refer to them.

See my answer [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/a-source-for-leaf-architecture-of-different-plant-species-genus/9208#9208) for links to examples, and also for some of the problems with using floras (e.g. not easily downloadable).

Comment: They really need to release a database version of [Mabberley's Plant Book](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/life-sciences/botanical-reference/mabberleys-plant-book-portable-dictionary-plants-their-classifications-and-uses-3rd-edition)

Answer (score 4):

**1. DELTA identification program key. (DELTA – DEscription Language for TAxonomy).**

http://delta-intkey.com/ , http://delta-intkey.com/angio/ , https://florabase.dpaw.wa.gov.au/help/keys/intkey_tutorial.pdf

**2.  FloraBase.**

https://florabase.dpaw.wa.gov.au/ (Australian Database).

**3. Royal Botanic Garden (England) and Kew Herbarium 's Database.**

http://www.kew.org/, http://epic.kew.org/index.htm  http://www.kew.org/science/tropamerica/ikey.htm,

**4. Actkey, maintained by Harvard University Herbarium**

http://huh.harvard.edu/pages/herbaria

https://web.archive.org/web/20170809022620/http://www.millersville.edu/biology/courses/471/4_471_Brach_Song_2005.pdf

**5. Taxacom, an E-mail server for discussion on systematics of living-systems. Monitored by University of Kansas**

http://mailman.nhm.ku.edu/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/taxacom (Taxacom main page)

http://mailman.nhm.ku.edu/pipermail/taxacom/ (Taxacom Archive)

http://taxacom.markmail.org/ (Post- Search engine)

**6. Angiosperm Phylogeny Website, under Missouri Botanic Garden.**

http://www.mobot.org/MOBOT/research/APweb/

> Source: Plant Systematics- Theory and Practice, 2nd Edition, by Gurcharan Singh, Oxford and IBH Publishing House New Delhi

Answer (score 1):

The United States Department of Agriculture have a plant database (http://plants.usda.gov) where you can download search results and checklists. Look at their [download](http://plants.usda.gov/download.html) page. However, I think that you can only download text (no pics), and it mostly (only?) contain plants found in the US. I have not used the download functionality myself, so I do not know anything about flexibility or interface.